# Funnelweb error installing transmogrify.webcrawler

Tags: plone, plone-funnelweb

I am trying to install the funnelweb add-on for the latest version of plone (4.2.x). I have tried this on 3 different computers, and get this same mistake on all of them. The error is pasted below:

```
magiq@magiq-VirtualBox:~/Plone/zinstance$ bin/buildout 
Getting distribution for 'transmogrify.webcrawler>=1.1'.
error: README.rst: No such file or directory
An error occured when trying to install transmogrify.webcrawler 1.2. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.

While:
  Installing.
  Getting section unifiedinstaller.
  Initializing part unifiedinstaller.
  Getting section funnelweb.
  Initializing section funnelweb.
  Installing recipe funnelweb.
  Getting distribution for 'transmogrify.webcrawler>=1.1'.
Error: Couldn't install: transmogrify.webcrawler 1.2

*************** PICKED VERSIONS ****************
[versions]
BeautifulSoup = 3.2.1
charm = 1.0b4
funnelweb = 1.1.1
mr.migrator = 1.0.1
transmogrify.htmlcontentextractor = 1.0
transmogrify.ploneremote = 1.3
transmogrify.siteanalyser = 1.3
xlrd = 0.8.0

*************** /PICKED VERSIONS ***************
```

Has anyone solved this issue?
    Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry about that. it was my fault. it should work now with the updated 1.2.1 release. If you have any other issues installing it feel free to contact me directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author made a packaging mistake and didn't include the `README.rst` file in the distribution.

*Update*: [Version 1.2.1](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/transmogrify.webcrawler/1.2.1) was released fixing this issue. Try installing again.

For future reference, when you run into such a problem, you can pin `transmogrify.webcrawler` to a specific version (such as 1.1) in your `[versions]` section:

```
[versions]
transmogrify.webcrawler = 1.1
```

or use `mr.developer` to get the development version:

```
[buildout]
# assumption: you already have mr.developer in your buildout
auto-checkout += transmogrify.webcrawler

[sources]
transmogrify.webcrawler = git git://github.com/collective/transmogrify.webcrawler.git
```

I filed a [bug report](https://github.com/collective/transmogrify.webcrawler/issues/4) to let the author know; hopefully there will be a fixed version available soon.

Comment: And also contact the author so he can fix the problem.

Comment: @vangheem: dang, did I forget to mention that? I filed [a report](https://github.com/collective/transmogrify.webcrawler/issues/4).

Comment: Thanks, i tried to reinstall Plone and funnelweb, and it worked. However, a new problem occurs when I try to import static pages. I'm gonna start a new thread, since the traceback is a bit too long.

Comment: @user1960836: Yes, it's better to create a new post for a new question. :-)